# Accessing a static property in a asp.net web-api project class from a console project class

Tags: c#, rest, console-application, asp.net-web-api2

I have a C# solution which consists of 2 projects: a console project and a asp.net web-api project (REST service); if I change a static property in a REST class from a REST client (ex. Fiddler), and right after I retrieve the value of this static property by using its getter from a console's class I obtain a different value (below the code). Any suggestions welcome !

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RestLayer.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ValController
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ....
                var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    string stat = "disabled";

                    while (true)
                    {                    
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        var stat = ValuesController.getState();                 
                    }
                });
                t1.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("t1 has completed.");  

        }

    }
}
```

The REST service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using RestLayer.Models;

namespace RestLayer.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {

        private static String state = "enabled";

        // POST api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Post(Command command)
        {
            if (command.Instruction == "enableBV")
            {
                state = "enabled";

            }
            else if (command.Instruction == "disableBV")
            {
                state = "disabled";
            }
            return new string[] { "state", state };
        }

        public static String getState()
        {
            return state;
        }

        public static void setState(String newState)
        {
            state = newState;
        }

    }
}
```

The REST client I am using is Fiddler. In summary, the value of the var **stat** I retrieve in Program.cs is different from the one (**state**) I set by consuming the POST.

Comment: This is slightly confusing - are you linking the webapi project in your console app, and accessing the `ValuesController` via a class instance, but when using fiddler hitting a web server to get the value?  What's the `...` represent in the console app?

Comment: **Hi Brendan**, in short I am using a HTTP client (Fiddler) basically for setting the value of the property **state**, which I am retrieving subsequently from a console class. The problem is that though the property is the same I retrieve a different value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static properties are only common to the current process. You have two processes here - a console app and a rest client.

To share the data between the two you could either persist the data to a database, but maybe better would be to have the console app make a call to the rest client and get the current state from it.

Your current "call to the rest client" just accesses the static property from the ValuesController class using `ValuesController.getState();`. To get the value from the rest client process you need to make a call to the rest api process using WebClient (or similar).

Comment: **Hi Jon**, thanks for your prompt response. Regarding your second option of **"...making a call to the rest client"**, I thought that I had coded so. I would appreciate it if you could expand on it.

Comment: **Jon**, I think I mis-explained myself. I am using a HTTP client (Fiddler) basically for setting the value of the property **state**. Subsequently, I am accessing this property from the console class. The problem is that though the property is the same I retrieve a different value.

Comment: The console app and the REST client (fiddler) are accessing two completely different instances of the webapi.  The answer here is to make the console app access the webapi via `WebClient` so that the console app and Fiddler are accessing the same webapi instance.

Comment: **Hi Jon**, Thanks for your comment ! It was pretty helpful, though I think I did not get it at the beginning because of my lack of experience.